# Campos Currency 1,99 salvando como 199 no Access

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

Estou com um problema quando vou salvar os dados de campos `currency` ou `decimal` em um banco Access usando os componentes do Visual Studio.

Quando salvo algo do tipo `1.99m` ou tem `1,99` nos textbox os dados vão para o banco como **`199`**. Em resumo a virgula é removida e fico com os valores multiplicados por 100. Como posso resolver isso? Já tentei coisas como `decimal.parse` e `Convert.toDecimal` além de jogar diretamente os dados nas *querys* que criei:

```
tableAdapterprodutosTableAdapter.UpdateEstoquePreco(id, **1.99m**);
```

O problema ocorre em qualquer operação tanto `insert` quanto em `update`.

Comment: Qual é o data type da variável que recebe esse valor (currency)?

Comment: Decimal estou fazendo um teste nesse momento com um Double mas por padrão é Decimal

Comment: Pesquisando encontrei o seguinte material, porém como usei os componentes tableAdapter e datasets em todo o sistema não consigo aplicar isso! mas segue o código!

Comment: Você comentou que tentou com 1.99 também... se você ir direto no banco e inserir 1.99 ele aceita?

Comment: Sim no banco tudo certo inclusive com aqueles comandos que eu coloquei abaixo na resposta também, o que eu percebi eh que parece haver uma certa incompatibilidade com o access e os componentes do visual studio (dataSet, DataTableAdapter) enfim aqueles que vc cria automaticamente ao arrastar os elementos do dataSource para o form, mas como falei... parece pois é somente com os campos numéricos de ponto flutuante que estou tendo problemas ja tentei alterar para Double mas da no mesmo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi editando diretamente no DataSet Designer, de alguma forma ele estava setando o providerType para Numeric, tudo que fiz foi alterar para currency
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Pesquisando encontrei o seguinte material, porém como usei os componentes tableAdapter e datasets em todo o sistema não consigo aplicar isso! mas segue o código!

```
public void Gravar(String Nome, DateTime Data, Decimal Salario, Boolean Status)
{
  using (OleDbConnection Conexao = new OleDbConnection(StringConexao))
  {
    Conexao.Open();
    using (OleDbCommand Commando = Conexao.CreateCommand())
    {
        Commando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        Commando.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Valores(Nome, Data, Salario, Status) VALUES(@Nome, @Data, @Salario, @Status);";
        Commando.Parameters.Add("@Nome", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Nome;
        Commando.Parameters.Add("@Data", OleDbType.Date).Value = Data;
        Commando.Parameters.Add("@Salario", OleDbType.Currency).Value = Salario;
        Commando.Parameters.Add("@Status", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = Status;
        Commando.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    Conexao.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Tenta usar o OleDbType.Decimal no Salario

Comment: Entao... esse codigo nao se aplica pq estou usando os componentes prontos do Visual Studio

Comment: http://www.databaseskill.com/2092815/ da uma olhada nessa tabela e aqui http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/data/System/Data/OleDb/OleDbType.cs tem a propriedade decimal sim! Por padrão ao que parece o Ole usa o Money e não formata corretamente pq o Decimal deve estar usando a formatação por resource culture!

Comment: Tentei de diversas maneiras, inclusive com culture mas sem sucesso, alguma ideia de como poderia fazer essa conversão?

Comment: Obrigado @Premiere consegui chegar a resposta pesquisando pelos seus links.

Comment: Tranquilo. Assim que possível marque a resposta que você postou como correta!